# How to add new value in existing cookie with PHP?

Tags: php

Idea is after every form submit, in to the cookie to be add new value, without delete existing cookie value.
Mayby it is possible with array, get POST param an put it on cookie, but how to do without overwrite ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cookie again, via the same means you set it the first time, will overwrite the cookie. So, to do what you want, you could append the new value to the old value and set the cookie to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies basically work like this: to set a cookie, the server sends its name and value to the client with a HTTP header in any HTTP response. After that, the client will send that key and value as a HTTP header with every request to that server.

So in order to "add" a value to a cookie, all you have to do is read the current value which was sent to you with the current request, add the new data, and set the result as a cookie with the same key in your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = $_COOKIE["TestCookie"]; // get current value of cookie and add it to variable
$value .= 'something from somewhere'; //append new value to variable

setcookie("TestCookie", $value); // set cookie
```

Not testet, but i think it should work. Just check if that cookie exists if not create new one